# Databases in java

Tags: java, ant, jdbc, hsqldb

i created my build.xml folder which create the connection with `database(startdb,stopdb,createtable,droptable,startManager)`...i run this and he told me that he created the table when i press createtable but when i start the startManager i saw the table doesn't exist...if somebody can help me

my build.xml:

```
    <property file="build.properties" />

    <!-- Global properties for this build. -->
    <property name="database.dir" value="database" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />

    <!-- Classpath declaration. -->
    <path id="lib.class.path">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Start the HSQL DB server -->
    <target name="startdb" description="Run HSQL database server with clean DB">
        <!-- Delete database files -->
        <delete dir="${database.dir}" />
        <java classname="org.hsqldb.Server" fork="yes" classpathref="lib.class.path" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-database.0" />
            <arg value="file:${database.dir}/db" />
        </java>
    </target>

    <!-- Start the HSQL DB browser tool -->
    <target name="startManager" description="Start HSQL DB manager">
        <java classname="org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing" fork="yes" classpathref="lib.class.path" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-url" />
            <arg value="${db.url}" />
            <arg value="-driver" />
            <arg value="${db.driver}" />
        </java>
    </target>

    <!-- Stop the HSQL DB server -->
    <target name="stopdb" description="Stop HSQL database server">
        <sql driver="${db.driver}" url="${db.url}" userid="${db.user}" password="${db.pw}" onerror="continue">
            <classpath refid="lib.class.path" />
            SHUTDOWN;
        </sql>
    </target>

    <target name="createTables">
        <echo message="CREATE TABLES USING: ${db.driver} ${db.url}" />
        <sql driver="${db.driver}" url="${db.url}" userid="${db.user}" password="${db.pw}" onerror="continue">
            <classpath refid="lib.class.path" />
            CREATE TABLE SALARIATII(
                CNP INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                NUME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                SALAR INTEGER NOT NULL,
                GRADDIDACTIC VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
                DATANASTERII VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
            );
            </sql>
    </target>

    <target name="dropTables">
        <echo message="DROP TABLES USING: ${db.driver} ${db.url}" />
        <sql driver="${db.driver}" url="${db.url}" userid="${db.user}" password="${db.pw}" onerror="continue">
            DROP TABLE SALARIATII;
            <classpath refid="lib.class.path" />
         </sql>
    </target>

    <target name="emptyTables">
        <echo message="USING: ${db.driver} ${db.url}" />
        <sql driver="${db.driver}" url="${db.url}" userid="${db.user}" password="${db.pw}">
            <classpath refid="lib.class.path" />
            DELETE FROM SALARIATII;
        </sql>
    </target>


    <target name="populateTables">
        <echo message="USING: ${db.driver} ${db.url}" />
        <sql driver="${db.driver}" url="${db.url}" userid="${db.user}" password="${db.pw}">
            <classpath refid="lib.class.path" />
            INSERT INTO SALARIATII(CNP, NUME,SALAR,GRADDIDACTIC,DATANASTERII) VALUES ( 1,'FLORIN BOIAN',2500,'PROFESOR', '07/08/1950');

        </sql>

    </target>

    <target name="all" depends="dropTables,createTables,emptyTables,populateTables" />

</project>
```

Comment: Hi, you should add at least the hsqldb and ant tags to your question and try to decipher a little bit the title... :)

Comment: Also, post your JDBC URL.  Does it include ':mem:' in it?

Answer (score 0):

If droptables runs before startManager, then it'll have removed the table, right?  Maybe you don't really want to run droptables?

Comment: I bet he uses the `all` target which calls the other targets in the correct sequence. No other target depends on `dropables` so it won't run "accidentally".

Comment: Makes sense as we just have the Ant build file but not how you call it. Do you only call the `all` target? Can each individual task be called by an application or script? In this case, as David said, it may be that the `drop` is called after having created and populated your table and just before displaying your manager.

Moreover, in your all, as you `drop` and `create` the table, the `empty` is not necessary.